# Jest returning error for npm packages that uses steal as their bundler like canjs v2.3

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, canjs

I have been researching and testing for months and I cannot set up my can js v2.3 app to run test with jest, and I couldn't find any clue into what is my problem.

every time I perform test with a module importing can, jest returns a failed error with this message:
[image: Jest error message]

Also checked in npm can/map/ I don't see index.js file or an export and I was thinking that this might've caused the issue:

[image]

My .babelrc file contains:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
    ]
}
```

---

and my babel.config.js :
module.exports = {

```
   presets: [
    [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
        targets: {
            node: 'current',
        },
        },
    ],
    ],
};
```

---

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Change your imports to can/map/map (instead of can/map/)

Comment: Thanks @JustinMeyer, but it returns with: 
ReferenceError: steal is not defined